# R: Ancestral sampling of bayesian network

Tags: r, sampling, directed-acyclic-graphs, bayesian-networks

I am trying to create a table with marginal probabilities of all nodes in this bayesian network:
[image: Bayesian network]

I have calculated the conditional probability distributions for each node.

Using the gRain package I have computed the conditional probabilities:

```
#i is the nodes number and P is its parents - if no parents P=0
1/(1+exp(-i+2*sum(P)))
```

I then created tables containing the conditional probabilities:

```
#For the three notes without parents
parray('xi', levels=2, values=(c(xi,1-xi)))
#For the nodes with parents, where j is its parent
parray(c('xi','xj'), levels=c(2,2), values=(c(xi,1-xi,xj,1-xj)))
```

I then created tables with the conditional probabilities:

```
#Levels to be used in creation of nodes - they are boolean, so yes/no.
yn <- c('yes', 'no')
node_xi <- cptable(~ xi, values=c(xi,1-xi), levels=yn)
```

I have then tried to computing the marginal probabilities using this code:

```
#Here where i is the node I am calculating and ji is the node given its parent.
node_xji <- cptable(~ xji + xj, values=c(table_xji[1,1],table_xji[1,2],table_xji[2,1],table_xji[2,2]), levels=yn)
plist_xji <- compileCPT(list(node_xj, node_xji))
nw_ji <- grain(plist_xji)
mp_ji <- querygrain(nw_ji, nodes=c('xj', 'xji'), type='marginal')
```

mp_ji look like this:

```
 #prob is the given probability
       xj     xji
 yes   prob   prob
 no    prob   prob
```

If I am to create a table from all these subtables (with probabilities for each node given its parent) how should I proceed?
Am I on the right track at all?